# c# image filter parallel.for takes longer time

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, image-processing, filter

here is the code is there any way to make it faster cause its slowerden single

```
public Bitmap pSetInvert(Bitmap _currentBitmap)
    {
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)_currentBitmap;
        Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
        Color c;
        Parallel.For(0, bmap.Width, i =>
        {
            lock (bmap)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    c = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                    bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(255 - c.R, 255 - c.G, 255 - c.B));
                } 
            }
        });
        return (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();
    }
```

Comment: Read your code.  What do you expect a `lock` inside a parallel loop to do?

Comment: Essentially your Parallel is useless

Comment: if i dont write lock it gives me that System Invalid Operation Exception error

Comment: You're locking immediately in the body of your loop. This defeats the whole purpose of using TPL since all other threads would have to wait for that single thread that is doing work.

Comment: how can i make useful @Jonesy

Comment: The lock is worse than useless, it is counter-productive because of the additional time to acquire the lock.

Comment: so how am i gonna make it better any suggestion ?

Comment: See http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

Comment: @hassan, to eliminate locking you could divide the bitmap into multiple arrays and process those arrays individually in parallel so threads don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Somebody flagged this question for deletion, but I'm marking it as "Looks OK", because it's a legitimate question. Having said that, I don't think it'll yield useful answers as they're kind of obvious, so I downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

By using `lock` you are making parallel part of your code to work serially, exactly like a single thread application with synchronization overhead so it actually would be slower.

here is a helper class that access bitmap data directly and you can manipulate image in concurrently.

**FastImage Helper Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ImageManipulation
{
    class FastImage : IDisposable
    {
        private Bitmap _buffer;
        private byte[] _rawData;
        private GCHandle _rawHandle;
        private int _formatSize;
        private int _width;
        private int _height;

        public int Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return _height; }
        }

        public byte[] GetRawData()
        {
            return _rawData;
        }

        public byte this[int index]
        {
            get { return _rawData[index]; }
            set { _rawData[index] = value; }
        }

        public Color this[int x, int y]
        {
            get
            {
                return GetPixel(x, y);
            }
            set
            {
                SetPixel(x, y, value);
            }
        }

        public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            var offset = y*_width*_formatSize;
            offset += x*_formatSize;
            return Color.FromArgb(_rawData[offset + 3], _rawData[offset + 2], _rawData[offset + 1], _rawData[offset]);
        }

        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color value)
        {
            var offset = y*_width*_formatSize;
            offset += x*_formatSize;

            _rawData[offset] = value.B;
            _rawData[offset + 1] = value.G;
            _rawData[offset + 2] = value.R;
            _rawData[offset + 3] = value.A;

        }

        private FastImage() { }

        public static FastImage Create(Image source)
        {
            var image = new FastImage();

            var bmpSource = new Bitmap(source);
            var bmpData = bmpSource.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpSource.PixelFormat);

            image._width = source.Width;
            image._height = source.Height;

            image._formatSize = 4;
            var stride = bmpSource.Width * image._formatSize;
            image._rawData = new byte[stride * bmpSource.Height];
            image._rawHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(image._rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            var pointer = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(image._rawData, 0);
            image._buffer = new Bitmap(bmpSource.Width, bmpSource.Height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb /*bmpSource.PixelFormat*/, pointer);
            bmpSource.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image._buffer);

            graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(bmpSource, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height));
            graphics.Dispose();

            return image;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _rawHandle.Free();
            _buffer.Dispose();
        }

        public void Save(Stream stream)
        {
            _buffer.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        public Bitmap ToBitmap()
        {
            return (Bitmap)_buffer.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is your code using `FastImage` class:

```
 public Bitmap pSetInvert(Bitmap _currentBitmap)
        {
            using (var bmap = FastImage.Create(_currentBitmap))
            {
                Parallel.For(0, bmap.Width, i =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
                    {
                        var c = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                        bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(255 - c.R, 255 - c.G, 255 - c.B));

                    }
                });
                return bmap.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lock` in the `Parallel.For` is going to cause the code to run slower than with a single-threaded loop.  The lock only allows one thread at a time to do useful work, with the added cost of acquiring the lock.

Additionally, GetPixel and SetPixel are *extremely* slow.  They are also not guaranteed to be thread-safe, which is probably why you are getting the InvalidOperationException

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Have a look instead at [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).  Though the class was introduced with WPF, you can use it from a variety of environments.  I recently used it in a console application.  WriteableBitmap can be converted to a standard bitmap if needed, or written to a ".bmp" file.

Alternatively, you can use [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) code to [directly access](http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i/) the Bitmap buffer.

If you need to, you can use multiple threads for either WriteableBitmap or unsafe access to the Bitmap buffer since you are directly reading/writing memory.

Comment: i just needed ready filters make it parallel iam not making huge stuff please help me about that

Comment: @hassan: GetPixel() and SetPixel() are simply not thread safe.  You cannot process your data in parallel using those calls.  You can use the unsafe method to directly access the Bitmap buffer (see link in my answer) and use multiple threads to process the buffer.  However, unsafe will be so much faster than GetPixel/SetPixel that you may not need the additional threads for small images.

Comment: They should have just called them `GetPixelReallySlow()` and `SetPixelEvenSlower()`, maybe then there wouldn't have been so many of these questions on SO.

Comment: @hassan How? You received a great answer, just follow the advice in it.

Comment: if i dont use lock the code doesnt work

Comment: @hassan: Replace `Parallel.For` with a regular `for` loop (just one thread).  If that is not fast enough, you will have to use one of the two alternatives I outline in my answer.

Comment: @Rotem iam not professional on this subject . just need help

Comment: mr @EricJ. for loop works fine but parallel.for doesnt work without lock

Comment: i need to make this code work with parallel.for

Comment: @hassan: You cannot use Parallel.For with GetPixel and SetPixel.  It simply will not work.  You have to use one of the other methods I outline to update the Bitmap if you must use Parallel.For.  I'm not sure how many different ways I can say that, so I'm going to just sign off with this comment.

Comment: now i got it thank you but stil dont know how to do it @EricJ.

Comment: Have you tested my code? It runs rather fast, imo..

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions of your filter routine you can play with. They take the image of one `PictureBox` and after running through the filter assign it to a second `PictureBox`.

- The first one uses `LockBits` and can do 10.000 (!) loops for a ca 400x400 image in 40 seconds on my machine.
- The second uses `Parallel.For` in addition to the `LockBits` and does the same job in 35 seconds here.

Of course these timings are strongly influenced by overhead (and maybe by dumb bugs I made.) But really, using `Lockbits` is key to speed here as there is so little to 'compute' the parallelization management itself eats up most of the cores' time..

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// ..


public void filter1()
{
    if (pictureBox2.Image != null) pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

    Size s1 = bmp.Size;
    PixelFormat fmt1 = bmp.PixelFormat;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, s1.Width, s1.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, fmt1);
    byte bpp = 4;  // <<-------------------set to 3 for 24bbp !!

    int size1 = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
    byte[] data = new byte[size1];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, size1);

    for (int y = 0; y < s1.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < s1.Width; x++)
        {
            int index = y * bmpData.Stride + x * bpp;

            data[index + 0] = (byte) (255 - data[index + 0]);  // Blue
            data[index + 1] = (byte) (255 - data[index + 1]);  // Green
            data[index + 2] = (byte) (255 - data[index + 2]);  // Red
            data[index + 3] = 255;   // Alpha, comment out for 24 bpp!
        }
    }

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    pictureBox2.Image = bmp;

}


public void filter2()
{
    if (pictureBox2.Image != null) pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();

    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    Size s1 = bmp1.Size;
    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(s1.Width, s1.Height);

    PixelFormat fmt1 = bmp1.PixelFormat;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, s1.Width, s1.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt1);
    BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, fmt1);
    byte bpp = 4;  // set to 3 for 24bbp !!

    int size1 = bmpData1.Stride * bmpData1.Height;
    byte[] data1 = new byte[size1];
    byte[] data2 = new byte[size1];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData1.Scan0, data1, 0, size1);
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData2.Scan0, data2, 0, size1);

    int degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
    var options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism;

     Parallel.For(0, bmp1.Width, options, y =>
     {
        {
           for (int x = 0; x < s1.Width; x++)
           {
                 int index = y * bmpData1.Stride + x * bpp;

                 data2[index + 0] = (byte)(255 - data1[index + 0]);  // Blue
                 data2[index + 1] = (byte)(255 - data1[index + 1]);  // Green
                 data2[index + 2] = (byte)(255 - data1[index + 2]);  // Red
                 data2[index + 3] = 255;   // Alpha, comment out for 24 bpp!
           }
        }
    });
    Marshal.Copy(data2, 0, bmpData2.Scan0, data2.Length);
    bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
    bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);

    pictureBox2.Image = bmp2;
}
```

Note that the 2nd filter routine needs to work on a second Bitmap for general purpose filter algorithms. This simple inversion filter doesn't really need it, but once you write things that access neighbouring pixels like eg.g a blur filter you do..

Also note the order of the channel bytes!

Comment: +1 Nice approach using Marshall rather than unsafe pointers.